# ¿Como preseleccionar un dato de un dropdown html que utiliza AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

Tengo el siguiente código de un dropdown select html:

```
<select class="form-control" id="anio" ng-model="anio">    
<option ng-repeat="elanio in losanios" value="{{elanio.mianio}}">
{{elanio.mianio}}</option>
</select>
```

Que me trae los años del 2010 al 2019, y quiero indicar que al cargar la pagina ya muestre seleccionado el año 2017. ¿Hay alguna forma de hacer un "selected" pero con angularJs?.

Answer (score 0):

Buenas pudes usar la directiva `ng-selected` igual a la expresión q desea q se cumpla algo como `ng-selected="elanio.mianio === '2017'"` por favor no recuerdo si la varabrle de ir ir dentro de {{}} saludos